# Combining Material UI tabs and basic Menu

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks, material-ui, onchange

I'm new to React and I'm trying to implement dynamic tab creation based on MenuItem selection.
I want the first tab to trigger the menu, which should open beneath that tab.
I want to be able to switch between tabs.
I want the first tab to contain an icon.

Based on [MUI tab](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#experimental-api) and [MUI menu](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#basic-menu) examples, I came up with the following code but it has some weird behaviors and after 2 days on it I can't see straight anymore.

The issues I'm running into are the following:
Sometimes the menu doesn't open, sometimes the tab gets created with the wrong ID

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm also wondering why the initial tab always has tabIndex of -1 and not 0?

```
import { useState, useEffect, React } from "react";
import { Tab, Divider, Menu, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import TabContext from "@mui/lab/TabContext";
import TabList from "@mui/lab/TabList";
import TabPanel from "@mui/lab/TabPanel";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";

export default function TabNavigator() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      title: "Home",
    },
  ]);

  const createTabs = (tabArray) => {
    return tabArray.map((tab, index) => (
      <Tab
        value={`${index + 1}`}
        key={index + 1}
        tabIndex={index + 1}
        label={tab.title}
      />
    ));
  };

  const createTabPanels = (tabArray) => {
    return tabArray.map((tab, index) => (
      <TabPanel
        value={`${index + 1}`}
        key={index + 1}
        // tabIndex={index+1}
      >
        {tab.title}
      </TabPanel>
    ));
  };

  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState("1");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue: string) => {
    console.log("handleChange");
    // console.log(event)
    // console.log('newValue')
    // console.log(newValue)
    if (event.target.tabIndex <= 0) {
      console.log("event.target.tabIndex < 0");
      // console.log(event.target.tabIndex)
      setAnchorMenuEl(event.currentTarget);
    } else {
      console.log("event.target.tabIndex >= 0");
      console.log("event.target.tabIndex");
      console.log(event.target.tabIndex);
      setSelectedTab(`${event.target.tabIndex}`);
    }
  };

  const [anchorMenuEl, setAnchorMenuEl] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorMenuEl);

  const [created, setCreated] = useState(true);

  const handleAddTab = (event) => {
    console.log("handleAdd");
    // console.log(event)
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.id === "basic-button") {
      console.log("event.target.id===basic-button");
      // console.log('basic-button')
      // console.log('event.target.id')
      // console.log(event.target.id)
      // console.log('anchorMenuEl')
      // console.log(anchorMenuEl)
      // console.log('event.currentTarget')
      // console.log(event.currentTarget)
      setAnchorMenuEl(event.currentTarget);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("event.target.id!=basic-button");
      // console.log('not button')
      // console.log('event.target.id')
      // console.log(event.target.id)
      if (event.target.id) {
        console.log("event.target.id");
        setData((data) => [...data, { title: event.target.id }]);
        // console.log(data)
        setCreated(true);
      }
      setAnchorMenuEl(null);
    }
    // console.log(data)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In the useEffect");
    // console.log('created: '+created)
    // console.log('data:')
    // console.log(data)
    if (created) {
      console.log("created");
      setSelectedTab(`${data.length}`);
      setCreated(false);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }, [data, created]);

  return (
    <TabContext value={selectedTab}>
      <TabList
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log("TabList onChange");
          // console.log(e)
          if (e.target.tabIndex < 0) {
            handleAddTab(e);
          } else {
            handleChange(e);
          }
        }}
        aria-label=""
      >
        <Tab
          value="0"
          key="0"
          label={<AddIcon id="basic-button" />}
          sx={{
            minWidth: "10px",
            width: "10px",
          }}
          // id='basic-button'
          aria-controls={open ? "menu" : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
        ></Tab>
        {createTabs(data)}
      </TabList>
      <Divider />
      <Menu
        id="menu"
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
        }}
        sx={{
          top: "50px",
        }}
        anchorEl={anchorMenuEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleAddTab}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem id="item1" onClick={handleAddTab}>
          Item 1
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem id="item2" onClick={handleAddTab}>
          Item 2
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem id="item3" onClick={handleAddTab}>
          Item 3
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem id="item4" onClick={handleAddTab}>
          Item 4
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem id="item5" onClick={handleAddTab}>
          Item 5
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem id="item6" onClick={handleAddTab}>
          Item 6
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      <TabPanel
        value="0"
        key="0"
        sx={{
          paddingTop: "1px",
        }}
      ></TabPanel>
      {createTabPanels(data)}
    </TabContext>
  );
}
```